# Prove that if $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ for all values of $x$, then $a=b=c=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

Could anyone help me out with writing this proof for my linear algebra class?

My classmate told me to just plug in 3 different values for $x$ and that should prove that $a=b=c=0$.  However, I could have sworn that this method is a big no-no for proof writing, because this only proves that those 3 values make the result true, not EVERY single value of $x$. So is this a legitimate way of writing this proof?

Other than that I tried simplifying with some algebra to get $x^2 + (b/a)x = -c/a$ but that doesn't get me anywhere.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try experimenting with "special" values of $x$, like $x=0, x=1$..

Comment: Since this is for a linear algebra class, they probably just want you to show that $\{1, x, x^2\}$ is linearly independent over $P_2(x)$

Comment: When you talk about this as a big no-no in proof writing, I think you are mixing premise with what is to be proven. It is true that if we evaluate a function at three points, and it happens to be zero at those three points, then we cannot automatically assume that the function is zero everywhere. But this time we are _told_ that the function is zero everywhere, and we use that knowledge three times to get a set of equations in the three unknowns $a,b,c$.

Comment: Ahh I see, in this case we CAN automatically assume that the function is zero everywhere, and therefore plug in values for x, because that was the given.  We're not trying to prove it the other way around.  Thanks, that makes way more sense!

Answer (score 3):

You're wrong about it being a "big no no".  You know that the equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$ holds for every value of $x$. If it holds for every value of $x$ then in particular it must hold for $x=1$, $x=2$, and $x=1204$. This yields three linear equations whose solution is $a=b=c=0$.

If the hypothesis holds, then the coefficients don't have a choice but to be $0$ and the fact that they are $0$ doesn't contradict the hypothesis.

Comment: Perhaps a more advisable choice of $x$ would be -1, 0 and 1...

Comment: @MichalFerov: and what about $\infty$ ?

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* Start with $x = 0$ and show that $c = 0$. Now use other values of $x$ to find two simultaneous equations in $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of the equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$ you can simply plug in three different values for $x$ and simply calculate $a$, $b$ and $c$ from the obtained equations. 
If you try to generalize this thing, then you can run into computational problems.

Suppose that $a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1x+a_0$ is zero for all $x\in \mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$, then all the coefficients are zero. This immediately follows from the fact that a nonzero polynomial can only have finitely many zeros.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a "clever" solution, I'd say that fundamental theorem of algebra states that a non-constant polynomial with degree 2 has exactly 2 complex roots. Thus this is a constant polynomial. It's an overkill though.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=ax^2+bx+c.$$

As for any $x$, $f(x)=0$, you certainly have $f(0)=c=0$. So indisputably, $c=0$.

Then you are allowed to derive the equality, and get

$$f'(x)=2ax+b=0.$$

Indisputably, $$f'(0)=b=0.$$

Finally,

$$f''(0)=2a=0.$$